# How to use two ssh comands in the same script and then continue executing other commands?

Tags: ssh, scripting

To login into my database the following are the steps I follow every time:

```
ssh unix_id@something.com 
password:
```

Once I am connected, I log in into a local database server in the same terminal:

```
ssh database_name 
password:
```

Then I do an su as:

```
su - appuser
```

And next I do the actual connection to sqlplus:

```
sqlplus ..
```

I am trying to automate this using a unix script, but I am not able to figure out the following:

1. how do I use 2 SSH in the same script
2. I could go as far as "ssh database_name" and entered the password, but then control returns to the terminal and rest of the script is not executed
3. I understand that after the second ssh I have to pass in the rest of the commands, starting with the su command as a parameter; but I don't know how to do the same.

Comment: you have to configure `ssh-keygen` so that you can login.

Comment: Are you using passwordless login (i.e. using keypairs with empty passphrases) or are you trying to hardcode passwords into the scripts ? Or you are just typing the password as they get asked ?

Comment: Thank you for your comment :) I am typing the password as they are asked. I have to do this as the passwords keep getting changed often and this script will be used by people having different unix ids and passwords; so I am not sure if I can use ssh-keygen.

Answer (score 0):

My approach to this would be two-fold. One, configure password-less keyed login for SSH via `ssh-keygen` as @Avinash mentions in a comment. Second, make use of `expect` to step through the two SSH sessions and the launch of `sqlplus`, then return control to the terminal.

Comment: Thank you John. Can you give a small example for this, since I am new to unix and not sure about how to use the expect to step through the SSH sessions.   I did try to use the expect command and using expect *$ and then giving the password, but I was getting authentication failed everytime.

Comment: It would be helpful if you could please put an example or point me someplace where this is already answered.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this, plus passphrase-less pubkey auth should do the trick:

```
# create an ssh connection for tunneling only, in the background (this assumes tunneling is allowed... usually is)
ssh -N -L 9999:database_name:22 unix_id@something.com &
pid=$!

# connect to the 2nd machine directly, using the tunnel, also run only the sqlplus command. (this assumes sudo is installed)
ssh -oPort 9999 localhost sudo -u appuser sqlplus ..

kill $pid
```

The first command can be replaced by a special config in ~/.ssh/config. Here's an example:

```
Host mytunnel
    User unix_id
    Hostname something.com
    LocalForward 9999 localhost:22

Host sqlviatunnel
    User unix_id
    Hostname localhost
    Port 9999
    ProxyCommand ssh -q -W %h:%p mytunnel
```

And then

```
ssh sqlviatunnel
```

Rename sqlviatunnel to something shorter.